Would a Wormhole exclude the creation of another wormhole in the warped space?

In this typical depiction of a wormhole, spacetime is folded to make the two distant areas closer together. Would that mean the "crest" of the "fold" in spacetime is incapable of having its own wormhole, as it is folded away? Or is this too literal an interpretation of the image? Or too 2 dimensional?

That "depiction" is a bit misleading. Only the curved surface (with the grid, stars, etc) exists, the ambient space it's embedded in doesn't exist, it's just an artefact of the representation. So those rays emanating from the top may look pretty, but they don't make sense.

Okay, but does that mean the crest can or can't have its own wormhole?

This is a large oversimplification and depends on what you mean by could this happen. GR does indeed have solutions that have a wormhole-like structure. You can definitely build solutions that have multiple such wormholes i.e. your "crest" can have wormholes as well. Now in actual physical systems (to the best of our understanding), the wormholes we see are not traversable.  However generally by picking the correct matter content (at least classically) you can build any geometry you like so also one with more wormholes. Though again this is not a very physical statement.
